# Django - is_ajax() not returning true

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I know there are a lot of questions already asked on this but I am not able to get around with it. Please have a look:

from a profile view when "update" button is pressed I want the user to be displayed with an editable form with values picked from database. So as of now there is no POST data.

template:

```
<form id="shw-form" action="/update_user_profile/{{r_user.id}}" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<button type="submit" id="upd-btn"  class="btn btn-lg btn-warning" onclick="update_profile_page();">UPDATE</button>
</form>
```

jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function update_profile_page() {


            var form = $("#shw-form");
            $("#upd-btn").attr('disable', 'true');
            $.ajax({
                url: form.action,
                type: 'get',
                success: function(response){
                    $("#upd-main").load(response); 
                }
                });

            return false;

    }
   </script>
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^update_user_profile/(?P<user_id>\d+)$', 'myapp.views.update_user_profile', name='update_user_profile')
```

but when I click on the button the else part of is_ajax() is executed.

Please have a look if you can find anything that I am doing wrong or missing. Thanks.

Comment: You access `action` of a form incorrectly. You should do `form.attr('action')` since `form` is jQuery object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the onclick attribute of the button, it may not catch everything. Use jQuery's submit() event handler (http://api.jquery.com/submit/) instead.If you don't see any request in the console, then Daniel is very likely right: the form is submitted the usual way.

Answer (score 2):

`is_ajax()` checks `X-REQUESTED-WITH` header. Usually `jQuery` sets it properly. You can try to explicitly set this header in `$.ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
   url: form.action,
   type: 'get',
   success: function(response){
      $("#upd-main").load(response); 
   },
   headers: {
     'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
   }
});
```

If this does not work, it means that your server or proxy strips this header.

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't work. I have tried it in Firefox-29.0.1 and IE-10. Is there a work around?

Comment: First of all see my comment about `form.action`, maybe it will help. Next thing you should check in your browser if it actually sends this header (using Firebug for example). If yes, than the problem is on the server side

Comment: I have changed 'url:' as you suggested and here is what firefox say about header:

Comment: Accept text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection keep-alive
Cookie <removed sessionid=pghst4nd947y1z738qupnb1adlivbjaf
Host 127.0.0.1:8000
Referer http://127.0.0.1:8000/user_profile/1
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0

Comment: What 'url:' did you change?

Comment: Oh, I see. Does it show any errors in JS console if Firebug?

Comment: Try using {type: 'GET'} not {type: 'get'}

Answer (score 0):

You're not disabling the default action of the button, so the form is getting submitted by the browser.

Since you've explicitly put the JS function in the HTML onclick, you can just do this:

```
<button ... onclick="update_profile_page();return false;"
```

Comment: I tried this but now button doesn't do anything on click.

Comment: Did you fix `form.action` issue? I think that's the only thing preventing request

Comment: @Daniel i have changed it as suggested but even before I was successfully directed to the url it's just that is_ajax() is returning false. So problem remains the same after changes as well.

Comment: Don't use the onclick attribute of the button, it may not catch everything. Use jQuery's submit() event handler (http://api.jquery.com/submit/) instead.If you don't see any request in the console, then Daniel is very likely right: the form is submitted the usual way.

Comment: @ecstaticpeon thanx your suggestion solved the problem. Too bad I can't mark it as accepted, only if you had replied directly :).

Comment: @jatinder Oh yeah that would have been better :). I'll post it as a proper answer, it'll be clearer.