# ajax test returns false even though the http request does contain the XMLHttpRequest parameter

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I have a function view. I want it to test whether the request received is an AJAX request or not, and do different things based on the result of this check.

The function is really unimportant. I've actually replaced it with a three line-function just to check if the request comes out to be AJAX, but the result is still false.

According to the django website, request.is_ajax():

```
Returns True if the request was made via an XMLHttpRequest, by checking the HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH header for the string 'XMLHttpRequest'. Most modern JavaScript libraries send this header. If you write your own XMLHttpRequest call (on the browser side), you’ll have to set this header manually if you want is_ajax() to work.
```

So in my javascript code I made sure to set the header (after creating and opening the XHTML connection):

```
request.setRequestHeader('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH', 'XMLHttpRequest');
```

Finally, I fired up tshark to look at the http header of the packets, and sure enough, the header field is there:

```
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
    GET /?&sort_options=most-comments HTTP/1.1\r\n
        .....
        Request Method: GET
        Request URI: /?&sort_options=most-comments
            Request URI Path: /
            Request URI Query: &sort_options=most-comments
                Request URI Query Parameter: sort_options=most-comments
       .......
    **HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH: XMLHttpRequest\r\n**  
       ......
```

So it's clearly there.
In my view, I cut everything out and at this point all I do is:

```
def ajax_view(request):
      if request.is_ajax():
      render(request, 'test.html')
```

But it is_ajax returns false. I don't understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unbelievably, after scratching my head and digging around for 2 hours and not getting it to work, immediately after posting this question I stumbled on another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23955607/django-is-ajax-not-returning-true) that provided the solution:

```
'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
```

**X-REQUESTED-WITH**, rather than the HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH, as the Django website says.